# Java Generics - quick question on Greater Than Method with Objects

Tags: java, generics

I have an assignment in my Java class, we are learning Generics, I have looked in my notes, my lessons, and even on the internet and I still cant figure out what this last assignment question is asking me to do, which is:

**Write a generic “greater-than” function that takes two objects as arguments, each of which has a “value” method which returns an integer and returns the argument whose “value” method returns the larger integer. Your generic function should constrain its type argument so that types without a “value” method cannot be  used.**

Is there a reason why "value" in quotation marks and how can a method constrain its type argument so that types without a "value" method cant be used. I'm mainly asking for clarification or maybe a little example.
Am I creating a Value class and then doing something like this:

```
public static <T> int greaterThan(Value obj1, Value obj2){ // Value will have the "value" method?
    // do I compare the objects here or in the Value class?
}
```

Comment: `<T>` does not “constrain its type argument.”  You want something like `<T extends SomeTypeWithAValueMethod>`, and then your method arguments’ types should both be `T`.

Comment: I would have never thought of that, ill try doing this. Thanks!

Comment: The instructions sound like they are trying to implement a `max` function, but call it `greater-than`.

Comment: I have to say you have a good class if they're doing this kind of advanced generics, instead of "make your own generic List".

Comment: My college has us watch YouTube videos for the lessons and then the "projects" are from a different college's curriculum so none of it matches or makes sense. I have been stugglingggg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are apparently asking you to implement a generic `maxByValue` method. Since `greater-than` contains a hyphen, and is thus an invalid Java identifier anyway, I'll stick to `maxByValue`.

The requirement of having a `value` method is mentioned a few times, so let's encode it as an interface:

```java
interface Value {
    int value();
}
```

Now, the main point of having a generic parameter here is to make sure that the return type of the `maxByValue` is specific enough to be useful. Let's call this type `T`. In order for the arguments to be comparable, `T` must be a subtype of `Value`. The only meaningful source for obtaining the return type is from the types of arguments. Putting together the three points:

- Type parameter `T` subtype `Value`
- Type inferred from the arguments
- Result type is `T`

gives you the signature:

```java
    public static <T extends Value> T maxByValue(T a, T b)
```

There are basically just two meaningful ways of implementing this. Let's take the left-biased one (i.e. left argument is returned if value is the same):

```
public static <T extends Value> T maxByValue(T a, T b) {
    if (a.value() < b.value()) {
        return b;
    } else {
        return /* left as an exercise */;
    }
}
```

Let's try it on a trivial integer example:

```
    class IntValue implements Value {
        final int v;
        public IntValue(int v) {
            this.v = v;
        }
        public int value() {
            return v;
        }
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "" + v;
        }
    }
    
    IntValue a = new IntValue(42);
    IntValue b = new IntValue(58);
    IntValue c = max(a, b);
    System.out.println(c); // prints "58"
```

So far so good. Let's see how precise the type inference is:

```
static interface Vehicle extends Value {
    String doGenericVehicleSound();
}
static abstract class Car implements Vehicle {
    public abstract String doCarSpecificSound();
    public String doGenericVehicleSound() {
        return doCarSpecificSound();
    }
}
static class Train implements Vehicle {
    public String doGenericVehicleSound() {
        return "tk-tk-------tk-tk--tk-tk--------------tk-tk";
    }
    public int value() {
        return 10000000;
    }
}
static class Ferrari extends Car {
    public String doCarSpecificSound() {
        return "rr-rrr-rrrr-rrrrrrr-rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr-RRRRRRRRRR";
    }
    public int value() {
        return 222000;
    }
}
static class Tesla extends Car {
    public String doCarSpecificSound() {
        return "...        ...           ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯";
    }
    public int value() {
        return 50000;
    }
}

public static void main(String []args){
    System.out.println(maxByValue(new Ferrari(), new Tesla()).doCarSpecificSound());
    System.out.println(maxByValue(new Tesla(), new Train()).doGenericVehicleSound());
    // System.out.println(maxByValue(new Tesla(), new Train()).doCarSpecificSound());
        
}
```

The point to see here is the following. We have the following subtyping relation:

```
Train   extends Vehicle
Car     extends Vehicle
Ferrari extends Car
Tesla   extends Car
```

and the following least upper bounds for the concrete instances:

```
LUB(Train, Train) = Train
LUB(Train, Ferrari) = Vehicle
LUB(Train, Tesla) = Vehicle
LUB(Ferrari, Ferrari) = Ferrari
LUB(Ferrari, Tesla) = Car
LUB(Tesla, Tesla) = Tesla
```

(and all symmetric cases too).

Now, when we

- put two cars into `maxByValue`, we get out a car (first example), but
- when we put a car and a train into `maxByValue`, we get a more general `Vehicle`,
  so that the car-specific methods become unavailable (examples two and three; third does not compile - rightly so, because a train has no car-methods).

Comment: You don't implement `maxByValue`, but rather just give its signature.  Was that intentional? - oh...that was just a name mismatch, yes?  `max` should be `maxByValue`?

Comment: @Steve 1. In my original code, I called it just `max`; I forgot the renaming in third code snippet, thanks. 2. I intentionally did not provide the full implementation: one character is missing. Not that it's hard to complete, though...

Comment: Cool.  I like how you put together a case that requires generics.   Great example!

Comment: Andrey, you made me complete my project, I owe you much THANKS! xx
I was having trouble with a couple of things and you made me realize what I was doing wrong. Learned more from you than in my class.

Comment: @MissIngrid Glad to hear that, you're most welcome. I've added an additional paragraph about the least upper bound, might be worth remembering that you already know what it's all about in case you encounter it somewhere again :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Let's define the interface with `value()` method
   *and provide default implementation of `isGreaterThan`*

We could make this interface generic (to work with the types bounded to `HasValue`)

```java
public interface HasValue<T extends HasValue<T>> {
    int value();
    default boolean isGreaterThan(T that) {
        return this.value() > that.value();
    }
}
```

2. Now generic methods should be upper-bound `T extends HasValue`:

```java
static <T extends HasValue> boolean isGreaterThanGeneric(T arg1, T arg2) {
    return arg1.value() > arg2.value();
}

static <T extends HasValue> T getGreaterGeneric(T arg1, T arg2) {
    return arg1.isGreaterThan(arg2) ? arg1 : arg2;
}
```

3. Let's provide some test implementations of `HasValue` interface and test them.
   *Note: implementations should be bound `HasValue<MyClass>` to restrict the interface to be applied to the same type (thanks @Kayaman)*

```java
class Apple implements HasValue<Apple> {
    final String type;
    Apple(String t) {
        this.type = t;
    }
    @Override
    public int value() { return 10; }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "apple " + type;
    }
}

class Orange implements HasValue<Orange> {
    @Override
    public int value() { return 20; }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "orange";
    }
}
```

Test:

```java
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Apple apple = new Apple("Golden");
    Apple apple1 = new Apple("Jonagold");
    Orange orange = new Orange();
    
    System.out.println("apple greater than orange = " + getGreater(apple, orange));
    System.out.println("apple greater than another apple generic = " + getGreaterGeneric(apple, apple1));
    // System.out.println("apple greater than orange generic = " + getGreaterGeneric(apple, orange)); // <-- won't compile: 
            // required: T,T
            // found: Apple,Orange
            // reason: inference variable T has incompatible bounds
}
```

Output:

```
apple greater than orange = orange
apple greater than another apple generic = apple Jonagold
```

Comment: Generics isn't redundant. It prevents you from doing `isGreaterThan(Apples, Oranges)`.

Comment: Its not redundant and i think this task is to get an idea for the important `Comparable` interface with its `compareTo` method. For this i also wrote my own generic functions like `public static function <T extends Comparable<T>> boolean gt(T a, T b)`. Sadly java still does not allow class extensions like C# and those fundamental comparisons are not in the `Comparable` interface as default methods. Your `isGreaterThen` function is a perfect candidate for a default implementation.

Comment: Hey Alex, thanks for the examples, what does the ? do in the getGreater method?

Comment: Its the ternary operator, if the expression before the `?` is `true` the first statement after is returned, else the one after the `:`.

Comment: @Ingrid, it is a [ternary operator](https://www.baeldung.com/java-ternary-operator) - a shorter form of `if-else` statement that returns a value.

Comment: @Kayaman, as long as both `Apples` and `Oranges` implement `HasValue`, the methods `isGreaterThan` and `isGreaterThanGeneric` are synonymous or I am missing something?

Comment: @AlexRudenko with generics you allow `compare(apple1, apple2)` and prevent `compare(apple1, orange1)`. With just the interface you also allow `compare(apple1, orange1)`, which may not make sense logically. Generics provides additional strictness by binding the `T` to the parameter type, so not only do both parameters have to implement `HasValue`, they have to be of the same type (e.g. both are `Apple` or both are `Orange`).

Comment: How do you implement this method in main?

Comment: There's something funny about this question and answer. It's the fact that the use of generics is being forced on the problem.  Because the only specification is that the code operate on objects that can return an integer value, there's nothing here that requires a generic type.   The only type involved, the return value of the one method that the class must have, is locked down as always being an integer. - I suggest that you can take the use of generics out of this answer, and nothing is lost.  Try it.  It works.  This problem is solved with normal, classic inheritance.

Comment: BTW, has anyone ever seen a definition of the form `interface XXX<T extends XXX<T>>` before? Can anyone point to a class in the Java standard library, or elsewhere, that is defined this way? Isn't this kinda just saying that XXX will follow normal inheritance rules? It says that it will operate on objects of its own type or one of its subtypes.That's normal inheritance, isn't it? I still haven't got my head totally around that definition.

Comment: @Steve No, it's not "normal inheritance rules", it's much more restrictive: [F-bounded polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_quantification#F-bounded_quantification). Nothing about such restriction is mentioned in the exercise, though, so I'm not sure why F-bounded polymorphism is used here. Looks like overkill.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin, yes, that edit was added to address specific comment to avoid applying `isGreaterThan` to different classes.  In the initial version of the answer, this difference was not provided.

Comment: @AlexRudenko Oh, yeah, indeed, this answer has quite an edit history. I liked variant 2 in version 1 most (but I disagree with the variant 3 though - that loses too much type information for no good reason).

Answer (score 0):

The previous example is a little complex, but all you're doing is binding your generic value so that it won't accept something that doesn't compile.

With your code...

```
public static <T> int greaterThan(Value obj1, Value obj2){ }
```

...the generic here is useless since you only ever use `Value` objects.  This *might* incidentally work because if you have a `FooValue extends Value` object, because `FooValue` is-a `Value`, it'd be seen as a valid parameter here.

(Note: this is how Java pre-generics was done: inheritance.)

What you're probably looking for is this instead:

```
public static <T extends Value> int greaterThan(T obj1, T obj2) { }
```

This is a bound such that the generic type `T` is bound to all values that are `Value` and its subclasses.

Comment: But where is the "constrain its type argument so that types without a “value” method cannot be used" requirement satisfied here?  You need to define Value, right?  It defines an object with a method that returns an integer, right?  Orange and Apple would be subclasses of that.  But then, the parameters in your `greaterThan` method could just be simple `Value`s, right?  What is the use of generics buying you here?

Comment: You should fix your answer so that it stands on its own.  As it is now, it's more a comment on the existing answer.  I know where you're at though.  I wanted to do the same thing...have the space and formatting of an answer to talk about the first answer.  I do get it.

Comment: Yes, this is where i'm conflicting.... I have tried doing it this way as well.

Comment: @Steve:  I never said it *did* buy any value.  I said that putting standard `Value`s could be just fine since this is how Java pre-generics was done anyway.  But whether or not generics makes sense to do in the context of this assignment is not what I want to address.